# How to list out all the distros available in windows subsystem for Linux in windows using windows PowerShell?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the WSL form Microsoft store and the I have tried to get the list of distros using the below command.

```
wsl.exe --list --online
```

But I got the below error.

```
Failed to fetch the list distribution from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/WSL/master/distributions/DistributionInfo.json'. A connection with the server could not be established Error code: Wsl/WININET_E_CANNOT_CONNECT
```

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDC7y.png)

Comment: That's the correct method.  If that's not working then something is blocking your connection to that URL or you have some other network issue preventing you from downloading the distribution list provided by that URL.  What happens if you open that URL in a web browser?

Comment: @squillman i am not able to open the url.

Comment: Ok, but what _happens_?  What is the error that you get?

Comment: @squillman Wsl/WININET_E_CANNOT_CONNECT

Comment: From your browser.  What happens from your _browser_ when you try to load that URL?

Comment: @squillman It keeps on loading and says "Hmm... can't reach this page"

Comment: Ok, then yes, there is something upstream from you that is blocking the load.  If this is in a corporate environment check the proxy/firewall or contact the IT department.  If not, then check your own settings or contact your Internet provider.  Check firewall logs, try Wireshark or Fiddler to inspect the conversation and find out what exactly the errors are.  Look in the Develop Tools of your browser (on the Network tab) to see what the response code is for the request.

Comment: @squillman Thank you